# Fiber product in scheme category

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X'$, $X$, and $Y$ be $S$-schemes. Let $f:X'\to X$ be an $S$-morphism such that $f_{x'}^{\#}$ is an isomorphism for all $x'\in X'$. Denote $g:=f\times_S \text{id}_Y:X'\times_SY\to X\times_SY$. Then does the equality $$g(X'\times_SY)=p^{-1}(f(X'))$$ hold? ($p$ is the first projection of $X\times_SY$)

I tried to prove the equality set-theoretically but it failed, but how can I use the isomorphism condition?

I forgot to say $f$ is a homeomorphism to its image.

Comment: Do you mean equality of sets, topological spaces or ringed spaces?

Comment: @DBS I just want to know equality of sets.

Comment: Hint: By universal property (of pullback squares) a point in $X\times_{S}Y$ is a point in $X$ and $Y$ which maps to the same point in $S$. Let $p$ be a point in $X^{'}\times_{S} Y$. So $g(p)$ is a point in $X \times_{S} Y$. But the map $f:X^{'} \rightarrow X$ is a $S$ morphism so your description of $g$ says that $p(g(p)) = f(p)$. So the point $g(p) \in p^{-}(f(X^{'}))$. For the other inclusion, take a point in $f(X^{'})$ and one in  $Y$ mapping to the same point in $S$, then this point actually comes from $X^{'}$  so it is actually a point in  $g(X^{'}\times_{S} Y)$.

Comment: @DBS Actually, I don't know why the topological space of $X\times_SY$ the set that you describe. I know it is true for the category of sets, but how can we say that in the category of schemes?

Comment: Dear @DBS: your description of the points of $X\times_S Y$ is  false. The simplest counterexample is $Spec(\mathbb C)\times _{Spec (\mathbb R)} Spec(\mathbb C)$  which consists of two points, whereas your description would only yield one point.

Comment: @User0829 I apologize for the confusion, by a point $p \in X\times_{S} Y$ I mean a map of schemes from $S$ schemes $Spec(\bar{k}) \rightarrow X\times_{S} Y$ (where $\bar{k}$ is any algebraically closure of the function field of $S$, assuming $S$ is irreducible). I didn't mean just a map of sets*. So, my interpretation of the equality above is that any geometric point on $S$ that factors through the left hand also factors through the right hand side.(Cont)

Comment: The map $f$ is not given as an open immersion so the image of $f$ is a constructible set and there is no canonical scheme structure on it. So one cannot interpret the equality as an isomorphism of two schemes.  *The universal property of fiber product that I have used is in Liu's chapter 3 Sec 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for any morphism $f$.

First, we have a commutative diagram 
$$\begin{matrix}
X'\times_S Y & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & X\times_S Y\\ 
\downarrow p' &&\downarrow p\\
X'&\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}& X 
\end{matrix}
$$
where $p'$ is the first projection. So $p\circ g=f\circ p'$, which implies that
$$ g(X'\times_S Y)\subseteq p^{-1}(f(p'(X'\times_S Y)))\subseteq p^{-1}(f(X')).$$

Now let us prove the converse. Let $x=f(x')\in f(X')$. Then $p^{-1}(\{x\})$ can be identified with $\mathrm{Spec}\,  k(x)\times_S Y$. As $g$ induces a morphism 
$$g_x: \mathrm{Spec}\,  k(x')\times_S Y\to \mathrm{Spec}\,  k(x)\times_S Y,$$
it is enough to show that $g_x$ is surjective. Let $Z=\mathrm{Spec}\,  k(x)\times_S Y$. This is a scheme over $k:=k(x)$. Let $k'=k(x')$. This is a field extension of $k$, and we want to show 
$$q: Z_{k'}\to Z$$ 
is surjective. Let $z\in Z$. Then $q^{-1}(z)$ can be identified with the spectrum of $k(z)\otimes_k k'$. So $q^{-1}(z)\ne\emptyset$ is equivalent to $k(z)\otimes_k k'\ne 0$. But $k(z)\otimes_k k'$ contains $k(z)$ so is obviously non-zero.

Comment: The last part may be replaced by the well-known fact that the map to the topological fiber product is surjective. Of course the proofs are the same.